# Visualizing pandas grouped data

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am working on the following dataset

[Dataset](https://github.com/datameet/india-election-data/blob/master/parliament-elections/parliament.csv)

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/datameet/india-election-data/blob/master/parliament-elections/parliament.csv')

df.groupby(['YEAR','PARTY'])['PC'].nunique()
```

[image: Grouped Data]

How do I create a stacked bar plot with year as x axis and pc count as y axis and stacked column labels as party names. Basically I want to display the top 5 parties each year by value, bucket all other parties (excluding IND) as 'others'

Want to visualize something like this [Election Viz](https://gramener.com/election/parliament)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC this should work:

```
sd = df.groupby(['YEAR','PARTY'])['PC'].nunique().reset_index()

sd.pivot(index='YEAR',values='PC',columns='PARTY').plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,figsize=(8,8))
```